# How to save a zoomed image from a web page

Tags: html, image, zooming

On a [web page where you can hover over an image to zoom](https://www.oushop.com/st-edmund-hall-college-hoodie), is it possible to extract the "zoomed" image (presumably a higher resolution image) from behind the scenes? There is no context menu on right-click to permit "Save image",

I have tried downloading the complete web page. The only image I see is the smaller one.

Comment: Please provide a link to url. Overall  answer is yes. If browser can show it to you, so you can download it. But in general you can check `network` section of inspect element of your browser and filter images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem**: you can't access that image because zooms usually use JavaScript. Images loaded via JavaScript don't exist in the HTML page - saving the entire web page only saves images that load on page load. Files loaded via JavaScript aren't saved.

**The solution**: a reliable way to download a zoom image is with the browser console:

1. Open the web developer tools with keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (on Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (on macOS).
2. Click the **Network** tab.
3. Click the **Images** option, so only images are shown.
4. Find the image you want to save - you can sort by **Size** because zoom images will be big. You can also hover on the filename to see a preview image.
5. Right-click the image you want to save and choose "Save image as". It will save to your computer.

The browser console looks like this:

[Screenshot of the Network tab of the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzfTt.png)

Comment: Your solution works in Firefox :)
I could not get result in Chrome!

Comment: In Chrome, use keys: Shift + Ctrl + I. Then refresh the page, so that the console catches all the images when the page loads. In the **Network** tab, find the image you require and double click its name - it will open in a new tab and then you can save it. To save it, right click on the image or use keys: Ctrl + S.